# Ubuntu 16.04 won't boot on my Yoga 260

Tags: boot, 16.04, lenovo

I have a Lenovo Yoga 260 with Windows 10 which I erased and replaced with Ubuntu 16.04 using a USB drive. After a successful installation, when I restart my computer however it will not boot. Does not take me to a grub menu either, takes me to boot / app menu [Boot/app menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQTXQ.jpg). All I can do is to reinsert my USB drive and if I cancel out of a reinstall, then it'll take me to the ubuntu desktop.

Can someone please help? I have tried going through all the boot repairs however that does not fix the problem.

Thank you!

Update 6/6/17:

This is the error message I see when the computer boots [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtNp9.jpg)

Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\grubx64.efi - Not Found
Failed to load image \EFI\BOOT\grubx64.efi: Not Found 
start_image() returned Not Found

Also when I go to my ThinkPad Setup page under Startup, Boot is set to UEFI only, I cannot change to legacy boot. Unselectable for Secure Boot

Please help, I'm not sure what else to do

Answer (score 1):

It looks like issue of different mode. You have installed Ubuntu System in mode is not matching (UEFI/Legacy) with mode you are booting os (UEFI/Legacy).

I suggest you to change boot mode from BIOS menu.

Comment: Should I change boot mode from UEFI to Legacy? Please see my update above, my computer won't let change from UEFI to legacy (Unselectable for secure boot)

Comment: Yes, In legacy mode you will be able to boot os. You can it from BIOS Settings.  You need to disable secure boot first for that.